# What are those + signs at the end of each stack trace line?

Tags: .net, asp.net, debugging, stack-trace

I was wondering: When looking at an ASP.NET error page with a stack trace you can see a + sign and a number at the end of each line.

For example:
[alt text http://employees.claritycon.com/spoov/SharepointDebuggingwithWSSV3_100BD/NiceStackTrace.jpg](http://employees.claritycon.com/spoov/SharepointDebuggingwithWSSV3_100BD/NiceStackTrace.jpg)

Also in the trace pasted in this question:
[Server Error in '/' Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680434)

The numbers are not the line numbers in the source files, so I suspect them to be something like stack (or parameter) sizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If it's in the **release** mode, it's CIL offset for that function in the DLL.
- If it's in **debug** mode, it's the line number in the source.

Comment: Cool, do you have any reference to the MSDN library where this is described?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe_members.aspx

Comment: That does not describes all the possible data that a stackframe contains, not what ASP.NET is actually displaying

Comment: True. But the only information on MSDN about what it contains is "a readable representation of the stack trace".

Comment: It's Exception.StackTrace.toString()

Answer (score 0):

In other languages (and therefore, probably this one too) it denotes the current position in the code, as a number of bytes or instructions offset from the function it is in. So in this case it got 173 bytes/instructions/whatever into Validate and then raised the exception.

I can't explain the 2049947 value however...